# Getting hidden text field with url to update image on hover jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I'm testing out some jQuery and want to update a image when hovering over a specific div or link block.

So what i was trying to do is when hovering over .test-block get the hidden text with the url and update it on .large-image-2. It can't seem to get the specific text on hover.

This is the code i have come up with:

```
 $('.test-block').on('onmouseenter', function() {
    let myUrl = $(this).find('.display-hidden').text();
    $('.url').text(myUrl);
});
```

Im testing on this page: https://jquery-testing.webflow.io/update-image the three bottom div's and bottom picture on right is what i want to use.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I've have looked at your page and I can't see where you have included the code

Comment: I think you ment to use `.on('mouseenter', function(){});` [mouseenter documentation](https://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/)

Comment: I just tried it on the console on inspect

@RamondeVries yes, i wrote it wrong, but that still wont work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few issues with your example. Mainly the way you register the event handler.

For jQuery the correct way would be `$(target).on('mouseenter')` - Ommit the `on...` part for the event you want to register when doing it through jQuery.

I would probably implement the functionality you're looking for in a less specific way and with simpler handles like the following:

```js
$(function () {
    let divs = $('[data-image-target][data-image-url]');

    divs.on('mouseenter', function () {
        let that = $(this)
        const target = that.data('image-target')
        const url = that.data('image-url')

        $(target).attr('src', url);
    })

    divs.first().trigger('mouseenter')
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div
    data-image-target="#my-target-image"
    data-image-url="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff&text=one">
    Hover One
</div>
<div
    data-image-target="#my-target-image"
    data-image-url="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff&text=two">
    Hover Two
</div>
<div
    data-image-target="#my-target-image"
    data-image-url="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff&text=three">
    Hover Three
</div>

<img id="my-target-image">
```

### Explanation:

#### Data attributes:

Two data attributes are getting used in my example: `data-image-target` and `data-image-url`.

Using data attributes on the elements you want the event to be fired on will make your script a bit more robust and less prone to errors, since the event registration is bound to the two attributes being present using attribute selectors for the jQuery selector `$([data-image-target][data-image-url])` instead of arbitrary classnames and/or ids.

The `data-image-target` should have a CSS selector that points to the `<img>` element(s) you wish to switch the src url on, while the `data-image-url` should hold the url of the image you want to switch to.

The code above could even replace your existing functionality for the top 3 images on your page.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

I tried to implement this now: https://jquery-testing.webflow.io/update-image cant seem to get it right..

Comment: The CSS selector `#my-target-image` is an id selector for an element with the id attribute `my-target-image`. You've added `attribute="my-target-image"` on the <img> tag you want to switch.

Change it to `id="my-target-image"` and it works.

Comment: In Webflow (the website builder i am using) it has reserved the "id" so is there a workaround for this?

Comment: There sure is! 

You can add `data-switch-image="large-image2"` on the `<img>` tag itself, and change the `data-image-target` to `data-image-target="[data-switch-image=large-image2]"`.

Comment: Never mind. It was a field another place. Thanks for the help!!

Comment: https://see-travel.webflow.io/ I tried to implement it here, but i cant figure why it dosent work.. do you have any idea?

Comment: The second section sand on the hover elements to update the picture..

Comment: It is working - It's just getting superseded by the srcset attr on the `<img>` element.
The code I provided is not production ready and should require tweaking for production use as responsiveness is *not* respected by it.

Comment: Ok, so the images is just too big? Is there no quick fix for this?

Comment: I found out of it, thanks for your answer. I just had to fix a setting on the img element.

Comment: They're not too big. The `<img>` tag itself has just assumed control of the responsiveness of itself using the srcset attribute. The simple solution is to quite simply not use the srcset attribute for that particular image. I don't know if that is possible with the webflow editor.

Comment: You should also remove the `divs.first().trigger('mouseenter')` from the script itself.
That was there to simply load the first image in the example code runner.

Answer (score 0):

This code worked

```
$(function () {
    let divs = $('[data-image-target][data-image-url]');

    divs.on('mouseenter', function () {
        let that = $(this);
        const target = that.data('image-target');
        const url = that.data('image-url');

        $(target).attr('src', url);
    });
});
```

Thanks to Morten for providing. With Webflow i also had to do Command + Shift + O to turn off responsiveness to the image. (when on image settings)

Attributes:
Name: data-image-target
Value: #my-target-image
And
Name: data-image-url
Value: (image url, in my case Webflow: https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/something)
These two attributes to each hover element.

Name: id
Value: my-target-image
This to the image element to show images. (if Webflow; "my-target-image" goes in the ID field in element settings.